# How to give Octomap data to the Planning Scene? (MoveIt!)

Tags: gazebo, rviz, moveit, octomap, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm relatively new to MoveIt and ROS. For the past week, I have been trying to configure the 3D sensor (a Kinect) on my robot model to work in MoveIt!, following the tutorial [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/perception_configuration.html). Additionally, I created a node to launch the  Octomap Server.

However, after completing these steps and firing up MoveIt!/Rviz with Gazebo, the Planning Scene doesn't contain any 3D data. I have checked the topics list, and my simulated robot is publishing the correct PointCloud2 data, and the Octomap server is running and publishing correct occupancy maps. What else is needed to get Octomap to publish the data to the Planning Scene?

Code:

config/sensors_kinect.yaml

```
sensors:
  - sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
    point_cloud_topic: /kinect/depth/points
    max_range: 5.0
    point_subsample: 1
    padding_offset: 0.1
    padding_scale: 1.0
    filtered_cloud_topic: filtered_cloud
```

launch/sensor_manager.launch.xml

```
<launch>

  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find inmoov_moveit)/config/sensors_kinect.yaml" />

  <param name="octomap_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
  <param name="octomap_resolution" type="double" value="0.025" />
  <param name="max_range" type="double" value="5.0" />

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274095/how-to-give-octomap-data-to-the-planning-scene?-(moveit!)/) by [MRV](https://answers.ros.org/users/32387/mrv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After talking to some people on the MoveIt Github repository and working through the issue for a bit, I figured out what I was doing wrong. (Mostly, it was a problem with my launch file)

Details [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/692).

---

Originally posted by [MRV](https://answers.ros.org/users/32387/mrv/) with karma: 16 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0